# 複数の値が入ったカラムから条件一致する行を探す

Tags: python, python3

添付のように複数の値がカンマ区切りで同じカラムに入っているテーブルから条件に完全一致する行を抽出したいです。

「str.contains」や「in」を使った使った実装を試してみましたが、例えば17が含まれているレコード（a,b）のみ抽出したいのに、部分的に17が含まれているcとdも抽出されてしまい困っています。
良い方法をご存知でしたらご教示くださいませ。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'product': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    'column_a': ['17,117,217', '17', '117', '217'],
})

print(df[df['column_a'].str.contains(r'\b17\b')])

#
  product    column_a
0       a  17,117,217
1       b          17
```

##### `pandas.Series.str.split` + `set.issubset`

```py
print(df[df['column_a'].str.split(',').map({'17'}.issubset)])
```

Answer (score 0):

リストにして調べる方法

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
                   'column_a': ['17,117,217', '17', '117', '217']})

df[df['column_a'].map(lambda x: '17' in x.split(','))]
```